# How long does it take till Google changes the snippets in the search results?

Tags: seo, meta-description

I have changed the meta description and title tags a couple of weeks ago but still in search results the previous ones are shown.
Did I make a mistake or takes time?

Comment: Keep in mind, Google may ignore your meta tags all together if they prefer other text on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on sites. Popular sites get changes early like When in youtube you publish a video and after publish change its description you will see that description changes in the Google search results too very fast. For my blog it takes at-least 2-3 days...